# In Opera, how do you NOT flag unread tabs with that little dot in the corner?

Tags: opera

In Opera, (version 10.5 at least, also I should be using the default skin), how do I disable showing that little blue dot in the upper right hand corner of unread tabs?

[image: Opera unread tab]

Comment: I tried to find such thing in the regular preferences, and as well in about:config, but haven't found, sorry. Maybe someone else will have better luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done using a different skin:

[How to Remove Opera Small Blue Dots Near Tabs?](http://www.favbrowser.com/how-to-remove-opera-small-blue-dots-near-tabs/)

---

For reference: the dots show when a tab in background has finished loading. It does not show for the active/displayed tab when it has finished loading, even if it has not been read.

Comment: Since it can't be found in options, using a specific skin which probably uses a transparent image (or none, I don't know how they work) for this dot is probably the best way to solve this question.